# How to auto fetch data and save into db from other api in api-platform

Tags: symfony, symfony4, api-platform.com

I'm beginner php, but in my project require fetch data from jira api. I'm using api-platform and I want to systeme can auto fetch and auto save data from jira api into entiy after a specified period of time. I hope everyone can help me. My entity is here:

```
/**
 * @ApiResource()
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\JiraRepository")
 */
class Jira
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $key;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $projectTypeKey;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $avartarUrl;
```

I want to auto save into that. How to create an automatic action in symfony? Help me. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Well it's really hard to say anything, because there is little known about your projects and what type of architecture and best practices you use in your project. I can help brainstorm into what you need to make this possible:

- At first you need to have an console command, which will be launched via cron tasking (**that should answer your specified period of times**)
- Inside your command, you will need to launch a service, for example: ApiService..., in there you will have to write a logic in which you will fetch your jira data (lot's of options here, **provided library, curl request, etc**.). (**I'd recommend, to have the endpoints written in an .env file, because you will need to authenticate, before getting the data each time.**)
- After you get your specified data, you should loop your data, and then call a factory and pass the data you need which will create your entity, bring back the entity in the service and then to persist and flush into the database...

Hope it helps.

Comment: I can understand your ideal, in my problem, I use **lesstif/php-jira-rest-client** to fetch data project from jira api, and how to create a cron task to save this data into my db? I want an example this problem, and I can develop more functions. you can tell me more about cron task?